# c# Remove older duplicates DataTable based on condition

Tags: c#

I have a DataTable with duplicated rows. The rows are equal but the Date is different and there are columns where there isn't a date inserted. I need to remove the older duplicates and remove the duplicates where no date was inserted. I have following code but it does not work because it can't convert fields into `DateTime` to compare.

```
public DataTable RemoveDuplicateRows(DataTable dTable, string colName)
{
 Hashtable hTable = new Hashtable();
 ArrayList duplicateList = new ArrayList();
 //Add list of all the unique item value to hashtable, which stores 
 combination of key, value pair.
 //And add duplicate item value in arraylist.
  foreach (DataRow drow in dTable.Rows)
   {
    foreach (DataRow drow2 in dTable.Rows)
     {
      if (hTable.Contains(drow[colName]))
       {
        if (DateTime.TryParse(drow["date"].ToString(), out DateTime res))
         {
          if (Convert.ToDateTime(drow["date"])<Convert.ToDateTime(drow2["date"]))
           {
            duplicateList.Add(drow);
           }
           if (Convert.ToDateTime(drow["date"]) > Convert.ToDateTime(drow2["date"]))
           {
           duplicateList.Add(drow);
           }
         }
       }
     else
     hTable.Add(drow[colName], string.Empty);
   }
  }
  //Removing a list of duplicate items from datatable.
  foreach (DataRow dRow in duplicateList)
            dTable.Rows.Remove(dRow);
  //Datatable which contains unique records will be return as output.
  return dTable;
}
```

Comment: _" it does not work because it can't convert fields into DateTime"_ So this question is about date-conversion? What type is `date` in the `DataTable`? If it is a string you should show us the value, then we can help to convert it. By the way, don't use `ArrayList` and `HashTable` anymore but the generic classes `List<T>` and `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>`.

Comment: That code makes my eyes hurt

Comment: How you determine duplicate rows? What is `colName`, what is `hTable.Contains(drow[colName])`(doesn't compile because  `DataTable` doesn't have a `Contains` method)?. What are you really trying to achieve?

Comment: Sorry i am new in C# and this is my second post but i try to archieve returning a DataTable with unique records based on customer_id. Date is a string in the Table the value is for example 12.12.2012 but there are also entries where the date is empty. If that is the case it gives me an error when he compares the two values. So i need a solution where he clears the older duplicated rows. When the date is empty and the row is duplicated he should also clear the row with the empty date value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want to remove duplicates according to the `date`-column? You can use LINQ:

```
List<DataRow> duplicateRows = dTable.AsEnumerable()
    .GroupBy(r => r[colName])
    .SelectMany(g => g
        .Select(r => new
        {
            Row = r,
            Date = DateTime.TryParse(r.Field<string>("date"), out DateTime date) 
                       ? date : new DateTime?()
        })
        .OrderByDescending(x => x.Date.HasValue)
        .ThenByDescending(x => x.Date.GetValueOrDefault())
        .Skip(1))  // only the first row of the group will be retained
    .Select(x => x.Row)
    .ToList();

duplicateRows.ForEach(dTable.Rows.Remove);
```

So first all rows which contain a date-value, this group ordered by the date-value itself descending, so newest first, all other rows are duplicates.

Comment: Thank you i will try it now.

Comment: The field is a string i need to convert it to DateTime. Values: Row[0] date= 11.09.2018 Row[1] date= NULL i think i need a try catch case to compare if the field is now empty or not.